# Bing Maps with pins and cluster loses click handler and has bad performance

Tags: bing-maps

I have a Bing map with pins and clusters.

I noticed performance issues and bugs in this combination. I have setup a [demo](http://s.codepen.io/nachtigall/debug/pPEMBe/xJMjOWWOqxQr) using code from the [official docs](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#customizeClusteredPushpins+JS).

**1st issue: Pins click handler are not clickable anymore after zooming**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load the above demo
2. Hover over a single pink pin => its clickable (cursor is hand/pointer)
3. Click on the + button to zoom in
4. Some of the single pink pins are not clickable anymore (cursor is default)

**2nd issue: Really bad performance when the map is initialised**

It looks like this is caused to many, many `_initiateRequest`, `_setImage` or `downloadImage` calls within the Bing Maps JavaScript. See this perf screenshot taken with Firefox Performance tool:

[image]

This performance hog drops to about the half if no `icon` param is passed, that is, in the demo this is commented out so that just the default Bing Maps icons are used:

```
cluster.setOptions({
  // commenting this out improves performance
  // icon: svg.join(''),
  anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(radius, radius),
  textOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, radius - 8)
});
```

N.B. in the demo *only the cluster* has a custom `icon` setting. The performance gets **much, much worse** if also *all the pins* get a custom `icon` setting. It does not matter whether the icon is SVG or PNG, both are really bad performance and the Bing Maps seems to trigger DOM events and old browsers like IE11 even hang for several seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the experimental branch. There has been a ton of updates added to it which address these issues. You can try it by adding "&branch=experimental" to the map script URL. The main release branch will be updated with the updates in the experimental branch in the next 2 weeks.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix the 1st issue, though performance is still pretty bad. Anyway, how can I find out that `branch` has been updated? Is there some kind of `Microsoft.Maps.VERSION` like there is `$.fn.jquery` for jQuery or `_.VERSION` for lodash? So that when I recheck in two weeks - how can I know it is the updated branch version then?

Comment: The bug we've seeems to have been introduced lately by one of the rolling release updates. Is there some kind of Changelog? Or a way to know in advance when a new update is coming (release schedule)?

Comment: The main release branch is currently updated every 2-3 months (was every month for the first 6 months after release). The experimental branch is updated 2-3 times a day. The experimental branch is updated once year.

Comment: "The experimental branch is updated once year." => I guess you mean 'frozen' here.

Comment: ah yes. frozen branch is one a year. Experimental is 2-3 times a day.